# How to scatter plot with colours assigned to specific factor

Tags: r, plot

I would like to `plot(x,y)` but associated with it are two other factors `z` and `t`. There are three levels in `z` and two levels in `t`. How do I do a scatter plot with assigned colours to each different factors and levels? ... which would mean a total of six different colours.

I'm considering creating multiple `.csv` file and using `par` but I think there should be an easier way to do this.

Comment: `with(mtcars, plot(mpg, drat, pch = 19, col = as.numeric(as.factor(paste(gear, cyl)))))`

Comment: Thanks db! Would you mind if i ask how to assign different symbols and include the legend? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe look up a tutorial on plotting in R using base graphics. You can assign different symbols in the same manner by specifying `pch = as.numeric(factor(...))`. For the legend, just use the same `col` and `pch`arguments (try `?legend`).

Comment: @Catalyst: probably easier using [`ggplot2`](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-essentials)

Comment: Thanks Frans. I managed to get the plots with different symbols. As for the legend, i didnt manage to produce it. This is what i have tried,

legend(x,y, gear,cyl,
pch=as.numeric(as.factor(paste(gear, cyl))),
col=as.numeric(as.factor(paste(gear, cyl))))

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want a single plot or multiple plots. Since you mentioned `par`, I'm guessing multiple plots. Regardless, to make two factors work together to make the correct number of colors, an easy way is to combine them into a new factor by concatenating them together with `paste()`. Here's an example with `ggplot2` and `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

DT <- as.data.table(mtcars)
DT[, combinedFactor := as.factor(paste(cyl, am))]

ggplot(data = DT, aes(x = mpg, y = disp, color = combinedFactor)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(facets = "am")
```

[image]